# How to find each string in a table and display them only once?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table which displays names, 0s and 1s, as shown here:

[image: excel table]

I would like to find each string in the middle table, and add it to the pointed table. I'm doing it by hand for now.

I tried to achieve this by using FILTER, COUNTIF and TYPE, according to what I saw on internet, but there is nothing about using data in multiple columns, so all i got is a #VALUE error.

```
=sort(filter(d3:l999; (countif(filtre(d3:l999; type(d3:l999) = 2); d3:l999) < 1)))
```

Could anyone help for that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use LET to simplify using UNIQUE and FILTER:

```
=LET(
    rng,    D2:L18,
    rws,    ROWS(rng),
    seq,    SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(COLUMNS(rng)/2,0)*rws,,0),
    it,     INT(seq/rws)*2+1,
    md,     MOD(seq,rws)+1,
    idx,    INDEX(rng,md,it)&"",
    SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(idx,idx<>""))))
```

[image]

And with a little change we can get the whole table with one formula:

```
=LET(
    rng,    D2:L18,
    rngN,   E2:M18,
    rws,    ROWS(rng),
    seq,    SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(COLUMNS(rng)/2,0)*rws,,0),
    it,     INT(seq/rws)*2+1,
    md,     MOD(seq,rws)+1,
    idx,    INDEX(rng,md,it)&"",
    nm,     SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(idx,idx<>""))),
    cnt,    COUNTIFS(rng,nm),
    wn,     SUMIFS(rngN,rng,nm)/cnt,
    CHOOSE({1,2,3},nm,cnt,wn))
```

[image]

Comment: This solution uses 9.5GB of RAM, but it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you don't need the table format

You could use solution "How to get distinct values in Excel (unique + 1st duplicate occurrences)"
https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/04/21/get-list-unique-values-excel/

And use a countif function to get the amounts

Comment: Thank you. I will keep that in mind in case nobody has a solution which would not require to change my table format.

Answer (score 1):

- Create an array of every other column of your data table
- Create an XML by using `TEXTJOIN`
- Turn it into an array using `FILTERXML`
- Use `UNIQUE` and `SORT` on the results

  ```
   =SORT(UNIQUE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,INDEX($D$3:$L$17,SEQUENCE(ROWS($D$3:$L$17)),{1,3,5,7,9}))&"</s></t>","//s")))
  ```
- *If your data table might have a varying number of columns, there are ways of handling that also. I wrote this for a known array occupying D3:L17*
- *If the string length created by `TEXTJOIN` > `32,767`, this formula will return an error.*

[image]